# Snort Inline Mode(IPS) Routing Packet Forwarding

Tags: http, ids, snort, iptables, port-forwarding

I'd like to build an IPS which would be a seperate endpoint than the router and/or protected servers. To achieve this I've installed to my Ubuntu server Snort with DAQ(AFPACKET). The instructions I've used is here -> [Snort 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 18 & 20](https://snort-org-site.s3.amazonaws.com/production/document_files/files/000/000/251/original/Snort_3_on_Ubuntu.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA%2F20201205%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201205T154636Z&X-Amz-Expires=172800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=c8f923f5db143d14988bf3e4c6c4437d3650b9d5e0d2ff96ee6b17d9ed601461)

I've built a local network which to simulate a real use case. For simplicity I'd like to focus on IPS protection and simple routing. The network I'm trying is below:

[image]

Now that I can perfectly configure the iptables to forward the outside(192.168.1.0/24) network to inside network (192.168.50.0/24) with such commands:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.50.100:80
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Seperately, I can redirect the outside(192.168.1.0/24) network to Snort's NFQUEUE

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -j NFQUEUE --queue-num=4
sudo snort -c /usr/local/etc/snort/snort.lua -L dump --daq afpacket --daq-var queue=4 -i enp0s1:enp0s2
```

Unfortunately I'm having a hard time to understand to combine these both commands to use Snort as complete IPS tool. So in short how I can make Snort to forward inspected 'secure' client packet to the webserver then back(of course).

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

IPS seems not to work without a bridge, right? [Here is a docker setup](https://hub.docker.com/r/karimkanso/gns3-snort#ids-setup) that may work.

This is my iptables entry:

```
111  5788 DNAT tcp -- eth0 * 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0  tcp dpt:8081 to:172.20.238.3:8080
```

Comment: I created PR with my current docker setup => I am not sure if your question is directly related => https://github.com/cfinkelstein/myownlab/pull/1/files. What we actually need is NFQ for NAT communication - this is what I understood so far.